# jQuery event (or hack) to react when a node is added to the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like an event be triggered when an element was added to the DOM. We could intuitively think about this:

```
//pick the generic selector of your choice.
//The naive idea is to execute this handler when an element satisfying
//  this selector is added to the DOM.
$('my-tag.my-class:my-pseudo-selector').ready(function() {
    // do initialization for element
});
```

But this does not work. Neither this does:

```
$(document).on('ready', 'my-tag.my-selector:my-pseudo-selector', function() {
    // do initialization for every element added to the dom, now and in the future
});
```

Since [.ready is only intended to work with document](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

How can I make a behavior -or hack- to be triggered when an element is added later to the dom? This addition will be performed by asynchronous javascript in one of three ways:

- Ajax .js responses.
- JS handlers for ajax responses.
- Calls like `.html('<my-tag class="my-class" />')`, or calls like `insertBefore`, `insertAfter`, `appendTo`, `append`, ... and calls like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Here is a example:

```
var whatToObserve = {childList: true, attributes: true, subtree: true, attributeOldValue: true, attributeFilter: ['class', 'style']};
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutationRecords) {
  $.each(mutationRecords, function(index, mutationRecord) {
    if (mutationRecord.type === 'childList') {
      if (mutationRecord.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        //DOM node added, do something
      }
      else if (mutationRecord.removedNodes.length > 0) {
        //DOM node removed, do something
      }
    }
    else if (mutationRecord.type === 'attributes') {
      if (mutationRecord.attributeName === 'class') {
        //class changed, do something
      }
    }
  });
});
mutationObserver.observe(document.body, whatToObserve);
```

Comment: Can you bring a small fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**DOMSubtreeModified**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified):

```js
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  console.log('document change');
});

$('input[type=button]').on('click', function() {
  $('body').append("<div>append element via button click</div>");
});

$('body').append("<div>append element</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' value='click' />
```

Comment: You are the one! Is the event cross-browser?

Comment: Wait! no... perhaps my handler behavior will update parts of the DOM, and I don't want an infinite loop. Is there a way to know which DOM changes were made?

Comment: I think it supported by all major browsers(not sure for ie7, ie8)

Comment: @LuisMasuelli I think MDN says if this event changes part of the DOM maybe will cause infinite loop and no others events listeners you register.